# unable to merge aws classes in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm having trouble assembling a scala project with sbt.  I have a merge conflict involving aws dependency jars.

I looked at a bunch of posts and I don't understand why my merge strategy is not working.

This is my assembly error:

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/jars/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.class
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.339.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/jars/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.class
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.339.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/jars/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSSessionCredentials.class
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.339.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSSessionCredentials.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/jars/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSSessionCredentialsProvider.class
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.339.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSSessionCredentialsProvider.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/jars/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051.jar:mozilla/public-suffix-list.txt
[error] /Users/xxxx/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.5.5.jar:mozilla/public-suffix-list.txt
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 20, 2020 9:14:32 AM
```

This is my build.sbt

```
name := "scala-redshift-connection"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

resolvers += "Mulesoft" at "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager" % "1.11.339"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc42" % "1.2.27.1051"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly :=  {
  {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly :=  {
  {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "amazonaws", "auth", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

I'm using sbt-assembly version 0.14.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're picking `last` of `com.amazonaws.auth`, which still picks it. It should work if you either `discard` the redhat or amazon one. In addition, you have to pick only one of `public-suffix-list.txt`.

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly :=  {
  {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "amazonaws", "auth", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(xs @ _*) if xs.last == "public-suffix-list.txt" => MergeStrategy.first
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

In my case I used a different library which also had a dependency on Apache `httpclient` and only had to pick `first` for the `public-suffix-list.txt`.